# React PWA not working when hit a refresh in offline mode

Tags: reactjs, progressive-web-apps, service-worker

I am working developing a react PWA offline mode feature. Everything works fine as expected in development. When I set the network offline the app is working fine as expected(even we hit the refresh in offline the app is working) but after creating the build and deployed offline feature is not working when I hit the refresh. Below is my service worker code.

```
let cacheData = "appV1";
//console.log("SW file from public folder..");
this.addEventListener("install", (event) => {
    event.waitUntil(
        caches.open(cacheData).then((cache) => {
            cache.addAll([
                '/static/js/main.chunk.js',
                'http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js',
                '/static/js/bundle.js',
                'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700,400italic,700italic&subset=latin',
                '/index.html',
                '/read',
                '/'
            ])
        })
    )
})

this.addEventListener("fetch", (event) =>{
    if(!navigator.onLine)
    {
        event.respondWith(
            caches.match(event.request).then((resp) =>{
                if(resp)
                {
                    return resp;
                }
                let requestUrl = event.request.clone();
                fetch(requestUrl);
            })
        )
    }
})
```

need suggestion mates.

Comment: use Google light house and test your app. Fix any issues/warnings reported. Also, check if the files you have listed above are available in cache.

Answer (score 0):

Try to go online and take a look into Network Panel in Dev-Tools. Than you will see which pages are missed. I think its caused by the react chunk-names... Maybe you can use precacheAndRoute()-function from workbox-tool.

Also i think you dont need this line: if(!navigator.onLine){}

Comment: when I refresh the page in offline, local storage data is getting deleted automatically. Can we prevent this ? I hope this will solve my issue.

Comment: Okay, weird. Mh, sorry i dont really now. Make sure, that you dont have toggled "update on reload" in dev tools.

Comment: Do you fixed "http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js" to "static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js" in precache Function?

Comment: I fixed the above thing @sniffles

Comment: As I mentioned previously I am working on offline feature. App is working as expected in offline but when I refresh the page I am getting this issue.